# Subscript out of range error (with array)

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have this code in VBS:

```vb
Dim Arg()
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
for i=0 to objArgs.Count
  Arg(i) = Replace(objArgs(i),"\n",vbNewLine,1,-1,1)
... (yes, the for has a Next at the end)
```

(example arguments: `"hello\nworld" "test" 0 64`)

But when I run it, it throws an error: `The subscript is out of range` (line 4, column 3).

Am I incorrectly using the arrays, or is the problem in the for, or what is wrong?

Comment: Indexing starts at 0 but `Count` is 1 larger than the last index. `objArgs.Count - 1`

Comment: `from i=0 to objArgs.Count-1`?

Comment: If you have 0 to 9 for example the count of the array elements would be 10. So at the moment you are looping 0 to 10 where the 11th element doesn’t exist hence the subscript out of range error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in VBScript are zero ordinal based that means that if you have for example ten elements in the array they will be numbered zero to nine.

So when using `Count` it will return the number of elements not their position in the array so you will need to minus one from the `Count` or VBScript will report a "Subscript out of range" error as there is no 11th element in the array to iterate to.

As [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73086314/subscript-out-of-range-error-with-array/73089772#comment129082254_73086314), you want to do this;

```
For i = 0 To objArgs.Count - 1
```

The other issue is you declare a dynamic array (`Dim Args()`) but never initialise it before trying to insert elements into it. You could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251363/692942) to a similar question that explains the problem. When using a dynamic array declaration you need to initialise it using `ReDim`.

---

#### Useful Links

- [subscript out of range while adding items to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251363/692942)
- [Visual Basic scripting dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664578/692942)

Comment: same error, even tho i changed it

Comment: I think the other problem is the use of `Dim Args()`. See [subscript out of range while adding items to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251363)

Comment: that was the problem: dimming things without a fixed length

Comment: You don’t need to have a fixed length, `ReDim Preserve` allows to dynamically increase the array as you go while still maintaining the existing data.

Comment: then i can `dim Arg()` with `ReDmin Preserve`?

Comment: Yes, see [Visual Basic scripting dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664578).

Comment: can i `dim Preserve` directly?

Comment: You have to have a valid dynamic array `Dim Args()` before calling [`ReDim Preserve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/c850dt17(v=vs.84)).